# Можно ли сказать: "Ко мне приходил (в голову) этот вопрос"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Грамотно ли так говорить?

**Ко мне приходил(в голову) этот вопрос.**

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: мне приходил в голову этот вопрос. Если "ко мне" - то приходила муза. Или белочка ;)

Answer (score 1):

Результаты поиска в Нацкорпусе. "Кто-то кое-где у нас порой" пишет: "...мысли приходят **ко мне в голову**" [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]. Таких случаев немного, и в основном они относятся к 18-му и 19-му веку. Думаю, в современном языке такое употребление некорректно.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве послания от кого-то вопрос может прийти и быть получен. В этом смысле фраза (*ко мне приходил этот вопрос*) правильна.

Фраза «Ко мне приходил (в голову) этот вопрос» — или привычнее — «ко мне в голову приходил этот вопрос» тождественна мысли о возникновении вопроса в ходе внутреннего процесса, а не извне, поэтому требует правки: Мне в голову приходил этот вопрос.